# pyqgis - Filter layer (LIKE) with variable

Tags: pyqgis, filter

I want to filter a layer with a variable and a LIKE condition.

The filter attribute is a timestamp column of Spatialite table. The table has also a join.

I successfully can filter this vector layer with:

```
layer_subset = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"acq_dat" LIKE \'27.06.2017%\'') )
```

The `27.06.2017` is the part of the timestamp string `27.06.2017 11:11:11`.

Currently I'm writing a small plugin for exporting Shapefiles based on different dates. With a combo box the user can choose a date und this will be the variable for the filter.

I tried this:

```
layer_subset= layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"acq_dat" LIKE \'%s%\'' % acq_dat ) )
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

How can I set a filter variable with a LIKE condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you have to post a question here to get the idea:

```
layer_subset = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"acq_dat" LIKE \'%s%s\'' % (acq_dat, '%')) )
```

Setting the `%` against `acq_dat` and passing `%s` twice.